# Django custom admin site doesn't work in Model view

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I implemented a custom admin site with a custom header and when viewing the "Home" and "App" views, everything is going well. However, when I inspect the "Model" instances, the header goes back to the default.

How do I fix this? Have I done something wrong or is it reasonable to consider this a bug in Django?

## Problem Demonstration

App View:
[image: good header]

Model View:
[image: bad header]

## MCVE

Make a new project and app, and in a file `sites.py` in the app:

```
from django.contrib import admin


class CustomSite(admin.AdminSite):
    site_header = 'Custom Header'
    site_title = 'Custom Title'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._registry.update(admin.site._registry)


custom_site = CustomSite('custom_admin')
```

Then, in your project URL configuration `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from adminfail.sites import custom_site

urlpatterns = [
    path('custom_admin/', custom_site.urls),
]
```

Also, add the app to your `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`.

Then, if you create a superuser from the command line and run the app, you'll see that the custom header goes back to the default when inspecting Model instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I finally figured out what I was doing wrong. I am copying the registry from the default admin site, but the registry is a map between models and their `ModelAdmin` instances and the `ModelAdmin` instance has a property `admin_site` that tells Django which `AdminSite` this was registered under. So, to resolve this issue, I simple copied the `ModelAdmin` and set the `admin_site` property to my `CustomSite`. If you change other stuff it might be good to `deepcopy` it, and this is a relatively untested trick/hack that may have other consequences, but right now everything is working out awesomely.

Here is the code in `CustomSite`:

```
from copy import copy
from django.apps import apps
from django.contrib import admin


class CustomSite(admin.AdminSite):
    site_header = 'Custom Header'
    site_title = 'Custom Title'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for model,model_admin in admin.site._registry.items():
            new_model_admin = copy(model_admin)
            new_model_admin.admin_site = self
            self._registry[model] = new_model_admin


custom_site = CustomSite('custom_admin')
```

Comment: When I try this, I get error "Reverse for 'app_list' with keyword arguments '{'app_label': 'XXXXX'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['admin/(?P<app_label>auth|authtoken)/$'] - any ideas why this could be?